# Grouping all JSON key based on values in Typescript

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, mapreduce

I want to create Two JSON from a single JSON based on the values. Consider below is the main JSON structure.

```
x = [
{id:"1",hobby:"videogames"},
{id:"1",hobby:"chess"},
{id:"2",hobby:"chess"},
{id:"3",hobby:"carrom"},
{id:"4",hobby:"videogames"},
{id:"4","hobby:"carrom"}
]
```

I want to create two JSON's based on the ID and Hobby. Such that each unique ID will have a array with its respective hobby and also each unique hobby will have an array with its respective provider

```
ID =[
    { 
      1: [
          {hobby:"videogames"},
          {hobby:"chess"}
         ]
    },
    {
     2: [
         {hobby:"chess"}
        ]
    },
    {
     3: [
         {hobby:"carrom"}
        ]
    },
    {
     4: [
         {hobby:"videogames"},
         {hobby:"carrom"}
       ]
    }        
    ];

Hobby= [
        {
          videogames:[
                      {id:"1"},
                      {id:"4"}
                     ]
        },
        {
          chess:[
                 {id:"2"}
                ]
        },
        {
          carrom:[
                  {id:"3"},
                  {id:"4"}
                 ]
        } 
      ]
```

Comment: why do you need to wrap each group in an own object and wrapped in an array? why not take an single object with the wanted group as key?

Comment: So that I can create two dropdowns which those objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply [`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function to build a dictionary wher `ids` or `hobbies` are keys and then run `array.map` to transform such dictionary into multiple array entries:

```js
let x = [
   {id:"1",hobby:"videogames"},
   {id:"1",hobby:"chess"},
   {id:"2",hobby:"chess"},
   {id:"3",hobby:"carrom"},
   {id:"4",hobby:"videogames"},
   {id:"4",hobby:"carrom"}
];

let grouped = x.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  let {id, ...rest} = cur;
  if(!acc[id]){
     acc[id] = [];
  }
  acc[id].push(rest);
  return acc;
}, {});

let result = Object.entries(grouped).map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try with the array `reduce` function. I'd also say having `hobby` and `id` properties inside the objects is redundant since the variable name already implies the meaning of the data contained within the properties.

```js
var x = [
  {id:"1",hobby:"videogames"},
  {id:"1",hobby:"chess"},
  {id:"2",hobby:"chess"},
  {id:"3",hobby:"carrom"},
  {id:"4",hobby:"videogames"},
  {id:"4",hobby:"carrom"}
];

var ID = x.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.id] = acc[curr.id] || [];
  acc[curr.id].push(curr.hobby);
  return acc;
}, Object.create(null));

var Hobby = x.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.hobby] = acc[curr.hobby] || [];
  acc[curr.hobby].push(curr.id);
  return acc;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log('ID: ', ID);
console.log('Hobby: ', Hobby);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```